# background обтекание

Tags: css, html5, background

У меня есть блок в котором находится таблица установленая через `float:right;` и текст который обтекает эту таблицу, я беру текст в `<span style="background: #color;"></span>`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу сделать блок, что бы он обтекал таблицу и в этом блоке уже разместить текст? Что бы получилось типо вот этого: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```css
html {
 overflow: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #181f4b;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: #969dcd;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 0px;
 background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 background: #FF0000;
}

.unselectable {
 user-select: none;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
}

.main-container {
 height: 100%;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

.fas.fa-ruble-sign {
 font-size: 21px;
 background-color: #ffb400;
 padding: 2px;
 margin-left: 5px;
}

.product-info {
 margin: 0 20%;
 background: #252f67;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.product-image-box {
 width: 100%;
}

.product-image {
 padding: 30% 0 0 0;
 position: relative;
 background: no-repeat center center;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #0a55f7;
}

.product-title-box {
 width: auto;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 padding: 11%;
 text-align: center;
}

.product-title-box > .product-title {
 overflow: hidden;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 50px;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.product-navigation-buttons {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 13px;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: 600;
 background: #3b498b;
 display: block;
}

.product-navigation-buttons > li {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 33.3333333333%;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.product-navigation-buttons > li:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background: #495aa9;
}

#product-navigation-button-active {
 background: #495aa9;
}

.product-info-content {
 padding: 15px;
 color: #fff;
 font: 14px / 1.4 sans-serif;
 font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.product-info-content a {
 display: block;
}

.product-info-short {
 border-collapse: separate;
 border-spacing: 10px;
 background: #3b498b;
 float: right;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.product-info-short td:last-child {
 text-align: center;
}

.product-info-short a {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.product-info-short a:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: 0.4s;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ffb400;
 transform: translateX(-2px) translateY(-2px);
}

.product-info-content .fas.fa-ruble-sign {
 font-size: 15px;
 margin-left: 3px;
}

.badge {
 background: #495aa9;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: .25em .3em;
 font-size: 80%;
 font-weight: 600;
 line-height: 1;
 text-align: center;
 white-space: nowrap;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 border-radius: .25rem;
 transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out,background-color 0.15s ease-in-out,border-color 0.15s ease-in-out,box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

/*reset css*/
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
   v2.0-modified | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* make sure to set some focus styles for accessibility */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}

body {
 line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

input[type=search] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

textarea {
    overflow: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
    resize: vertical;
}

/**
 * Correct `inline-block` display not defined in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 */

audio,
canvas,
video {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}

/**
 * Prevent modern browsers from displaying `audio` without controls.
 * Remove excess height in iOS 5 devices.
 */

audio:not([controls]) {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 7/8/9, Firefox 3, and Safari 4.
 * Known issue: no IE 6 support.
 */

[hidden] {
    display: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct text resizing oddly in IE 6/7 when body `font-size` is set using
 *    `em` units.
 * 2. Prevent iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling
 *    user zoom.
 */

html {
    font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Address `outline` inconsistency between Chrome and other browsers.
 */

a:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
}

/**
 * Improve readability when focused and also mouse hovered in all browsers.
 */

a:active,
a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}

/**
 * 1. Remove border when inside `a` element in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 * 2. Improve image quality when scaled in IE 7.
 */

img {
    border: 0; /* 1 */
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Address margin not present in IE 6/7/8/9, Safari 5, and Opera 11.
 */

figure {
    margin: 0;
}

/**
 * Correct margin displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */

form {
    margin: 0;
}

/**
 * Define consistent border, margin, and padding.
 */

fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct color not being inherited in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Correct text not wrapping in Firefox 3.
 * 3. Correct alignment displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */

legend {
    border: 0; /* 1 */
    padding: 0;
    white-space: normal; /* 2 */
    *margin-left: -7px; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * 1. Correct font size not being inherited in all browsers.
 * 2. Address margins set differently in IE 6/7, Firefox 3+, Safari 5,
 *    and Chrome.
 * 3. Improve appearance and consistency in all browsers.
 */

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
    margin: 0; /* 2 */
    vertical-align: baseline; /* 3 */
    *vertical-align: middle; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * Address Firefox 3+ setting `line-height` on `input` using `!important` in
 * the UA stylesheet.
 */

button,
input {
    line-height: normal;
}

/**
 * Address inconsistent `text-transform` inheritance for `button` and `select`.
 * All other form control elements do not inherit `text-transform` values.
 * Correct `button` style inheritance in Chrome, Safari 5+, and IE 6+.
 * Correct `select` style inheritance in Firefox 4+ and Opera.
 */

button,
select {
    text-transform: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Avoid the WebKit bug in Android 4.0.* where (2) destroys native `audio`
 *    and `video` controls.
 * 2. Correct inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS.
 * 3. Improve usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type
 *    `input` and others.
 * 4. Remove inner spacing in IE 7 without affecting normal text inputs.
 *    Known issue: inner spacing remains in IE 6.
 */

button,
html input[type="button"], /* 1 */
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button; /* 2 */
    cursor: pointer; /* 3 */
    *overflow: visible;  /* 4 */
}

/**
 * Re-set default cursor for disabled elements.
 */

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
}

/**
 * 1. Address box sizing set to content-box in IE 8/9.
 * 2. Remove excess padding in IE 8/9.
 * 3. Remove excess padding in IE 7.
 *    Known issue: excess padding remains in IE 6.
 */

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
    padding: 0; /* 2 */
    *height: 13px; /* 3 */
    *width: 13px; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * 1. Address `appearance` set to `searchfield` in Safari 5 and Chrome.
 * 2. Address `box-sizing` set to `border-box` in Safari 5 and Chrome
 *    (include `-moz` to future-proof).
 */

input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /* 2 */
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and search cancel button in Safari 5 and Chrome
 * on OS X.
 */

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and border in Firefox 3+.
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/**
 * 1. Remove default vertical scrollbar in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Improve readability and alignment in all browsers.
 */

textarea {
    overflow: auto; /* 1 */
    vertical-align: top; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove most spacing between table cells.
 */

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: rgb(59,173,227);
}


::-moz-selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

fieldset {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

textarea {
    resize: vertical;
}

.chromeframe {
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.2em 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>Ultimate Shop</title>
 <link href="css/reset.css"    rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/main.css"    rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/adaptive.css"   rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/tooltip.css"   rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/range.css"    rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- <link href="css/slider.css"   rel="stylesheet"> -->
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content">
        <div class="product-info">
     <div class="product-image-box">
      <div class="product-image" style="background-image: url('.$row['image'].');">
       <div class="product-title-box">
        <p class="product-title unselectable">Ultimate Arena</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <ul class="product-navigation-buttons unselectable">
      <li class="product-description-button" id="product-navigation-button-active">Описание</li><li class="product-setting-button">Настройки</li><li class="product-install-button">Установка</li>
     </ul>
     <div class="product-info-content">
      <table class="product-info-short unselectable">
       <tr>
        <td>Версия:</td>
        <td>1.0.0</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Автор:</td>
        <td>Nunf</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Файлы входящие в плагин:</td>
        <td>
         <a class="badge">ultimate_arena.cfg</a>
         <a class="badge">ultimate_arena.cfg</a>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Стоимость:</td>
        <td>999<i class="fas fa-ruble-sign" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
            <span style="background: #3b498b;">В процессе изучения материалов форума всё-таки решил написать краткую компиляцию литературы по обсуждаемому вопросу (в частности, диетам и "здоровому питанию"). Если кому-то интересно откуда я взял всё изложенное ниже - я приведу список литературы для подробного изучения. Ещё извиняюсь, если при упрощении материала где-то допустил неточность или искажение - прошу указать и поправить. Только, чур, аргументированно а не вот так: "я слышала, так не бывает" или "а я - не такая". Так же для чтения всего этого хорошо бы знать что такое обмен веществ (метаболизм), основной обмен веществ, белки, жиры, "быстрые" и "медленные" углеводы, калории, низкий и высокий гликемический индекс. В организме человека есть два источника энергии - гликоген (полисахарид), запасается в печени и мышечной ткани. Человек весом 75 кг может запасти 400 грамм гликогена ы мышцах (это 1600 ккал) и 80 грамм - в печени (320 ккал). Итого - 1920 ккал. Гликоген мышц используы мышцах (это 1600 ккал) и 80 грамм - в печени (320 ккал). Итого - 1920 ккал. Гликоген мышц используется непосредственно мышцой для покрытия собственных энергетических затрат, гликоген печени позволяет поддержать на определённом уровне уровень сахара в крови в целом, что бы "в случае чего" восполнить нехватку там где он (гликоген) нужен. А вот в жировой ткани можно спрятать намного больше энергии. 1 кг жира - это почти 8750 ккал. Но и нужны они не в повседневной жизни, по крайней мере человеку, который нормально питается и не голодает. Жир спасает животных (и человека) в экстремальных условиях - когда запасы гликогена почти исчерпаны. Ещё спасает от холода - но я видел мало людей которые пользуются своим жиром в этом направлении. То есть, если человек решил поголодать, например, "по Малахову", то организм будет действовать в такой последовательности: 1) поживёт недельку на остатках гликогена, ожидая нормального питания, попутно замедлянедельку на остатках гликогена, ожидая нормального питания, попутно замедляя обмен веществ что бы адаптироваться к новой схеме энергоснабжения. К концу 2-3 дня начнёт пережигать мышечную ткань (процесс катаболизма), так как этим убъёт сразу двух зайцев - килограмм мышц "съедает" 50 ккал в день, и в то же время они являются более легкоусвояемым топливом по сравнению с жиром. 2) Когда организм через неделю-две понимает, что здравый смысл в хозяине всё ещё не победил (у всех этот процесс "размышлений" занимает разное время, я имею в виду "размышления" организма, а не хозяина - там всё сложнее :-) ) - переходит на использование жировых запасов, но обмен веществ тормозить не перестаёт. Вспомните медведей, как они впадают в спячку - у них жира полно, они 3-4 месяца им могут питаться не напрягаясь. Правда, в спячке у них в разы замедляется дыхание, пульс, мозговая активность и падает давление и температура тела. Но если вам в реальных условиях это не помешат, например, ходить на работу (да ещё и работать) - остаётся только позавидовать вашей работе, если там ещё и платят нормально. Вам тогда можно голодать. Итак, для того что бы эффективно бороться с жиром для начала следует узнать а откуда он берётся в таких количествах, что приводит к росту жировой ткани, а что - к её исчезновению. Жировая ткань - это, как известно, совокупность жировых клеток (адипоцитов). Жировая ткань бывает двух видов - белая и бурая, но, поскольку в организме взрослого человека бурой жировой ткани мало, мы её рассматривать не будем. Жировая клетка (белой ткани) представляет собой шарик, внутри которого находится жировой пузырёк. О ней важно знать два факта: 1) По мере накопления внутри клетки жира (триглицеридов), клетка "раздувается", но раздуваться до бесконечности она не может, у неё есть предел. 2) В организме человека есть уже сформировавшиеся жировые клетки и запас (2-3 раза больший по числу) так называемых "вспомогательных" жировых клеток, которые не могут накапливать жир, но легко (и необратимо!) эволюционируют в жировую клетку если соседние с ней клетки забиты запасами жира "до упора". Вывод №1: количество жировой ткани за счёт количества клеток может только расти. А наша задача - не доводить имеющуюся ткань до такого состояния. Вывод №2: Ещё одно следствие - жировые клетки не могут "сгореть", а только уменьшиться в размерах за счёт опорожнения и переработки их внутренних запасов. Теперь стоит сказать по поводу распределения запасов жира в организме. Жировая клетка содержит 2 типа рецепторов, позволяющих ей понять что же от неё требуется - запасти жир или отдать его на "переработку". Это так называемые альфа-2- и бета-рецепторы. Рецепторы "вылавливают" из крови гормоны (в нашем случае важны: адреналин и норадреналин, инсулин и глюкогон) и либо запускают процесс синтеза в клетке жира (вылавливая так же из крови жирные кислоты и глюкозу), это называется липогенезом, либо опорожняют клетку, насыщая кровь запасёнными жирными кислотами (это липолиз - самый полезный для наших целей процесс) . Альфа рецепторы отвечают за липогенез, бета-рецепторы - за липолиз. Самый примечательный для нас факт: жировая ткань на бёдрах, ягодицах, внутренней поверхности бедра, вообщем весь низ тела - более насыщены альфа-рецепторами, в то время как верх тела - бета-рецепторами. Поэтому "низ" отдаёт жиры очень неохотно, зато грудь худеет "на ура". В западных источниках есть публикации по поводу возможности вырождения жировой клетки до её первоначального состояния, но вырождения жировой клетки до её первоначального состояния, но ещё нет доказательств, что такой процесс вообще возможен в организме. Когда будет - проблема лишнего веса будет решена раз и навсегда Вывод №1: количество жировой ткани за счёт количества клеток может только расти. А наша задача - не доводить имеющуюся ткань до такого состояния. Вывод №2: Ещё одно следствие - жировые клетки не могут "сгореть", а только уменьшиться в размерах за счёт опорожнения и переработки их внутренних запасов. ----------- Продолжение, часть 2-ая и не последняя ---------------- Снова подведу некоторые итоги предыдущей части что бы облегчить понимание следующей (если что-то не понятно - срочно читать начало): - Стимулирующее воздействие на липолиз оказывают глюкагон (ещё соматотропин - гормон роста, но механизмы их действия различны и находятся за рамками нашей темы). - Тормозящее липолиз (и стимулирующее липогенез) действие оказывает инсулин. - Адреналин и норадреналин так же активизируют ферменты, необходимые для липолиза. При сильном стрессе интенсивное расщепление липидов является одной из причин потери веса. Итого: хотим худеть - держим уровень сахара на постоянном уровне, не допускаем его скачков (в рационе преобладают медленные углеводы), не даём жировой клетке материа(в рационе преобладают медленные углеводы), не даём жировой клетке материалов для строительства нового запаса жиров (триглициридов) (не допускаем значительного потребления жирного вместе со сладким за один приём пищи). Этого достаточно что бы не толстеть. Но..... чаще-то хочется убрать всё что уже нажито непосильным трудом. Да и, в конце концов, привлекательная, подтянутая фигура - это хорошо, но для многих не может быть целью жизни, и в этой самой жизни есть ещё куча других радостей, если не торты, то, по крайней мере, посиделки с подругами в суши-баре. То есть наша цель - балансировать около уровня вашего выбранного "идеального" веса. Поэтому, теперь когда нам известно какие процессы идут в ораганизме и что их регулирует рассмотрим два пути расходы лишнего жира: Голодание. Ничего нового сказать не могу, про медведя я уже писал. Важно знать, что если кто-то говорит что "я голодал три недели, потерял 30 кг, со 150 до 120" - это не значит что вы можете за неделю скинуть десятку. </span>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот как я хочу сделать: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: код предоставить можно данного куска? Картинки здесь не приветствуются

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас добавлю код

Comment: <div style="float:left"> ?

Answer (score 0):

Просто используйте `<p>` вместо `<span>`.

```css
html {
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #181f4b;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #969dcd;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #FF0000;
}

.unselectable {
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.main-container {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.fas.fa-ruble-sign {
  font-size: 21px;
  background-color: #ffb400;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.product-info {
  margin: 0 20%;
  background: #252f67;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.product-image-box {
  width: 100%;
}

.product-image {
  padding: 30% 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  background: no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #0a55f7;
}

.product-title-box {
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 11%;
  text-align: center;
}

.product-title-box>.product-title {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.product-navigation-buttons {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: #3b498b;
  display: block;
}

.product-navigation-buttons>li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.3333333333%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.product-navigation-buttons>li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #495aa9;
}

#product-navigation-button-active {
  background: #495aa9;
}

.product-info-content {
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font: 14px / 1.4 sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.product-info-content a {
  display: block;
}

.product-info-short {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  background: #3b498b;
  float: right;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.product-info-short td:last-child {
  text-align: center;
}

.product-info-short a {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.product-info-short a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ffb400;
  transform: translateX(-2px) translateY(-2px);
}

.product-info-content .fas.fa-ruble-sign {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.badge {
  background: #495aa9;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .25em .3em;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}


/*reset css*/


/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
   v2.0-modified | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* make sure to set some focus styles for accessibility */

:focus {
  outline: 0;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

input[type=search] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  resize: vertical;
}


/**
 * Correct `inline-block` display not defined in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 */

audio,
canvas,
video {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/**
 * Prevent modern browsers from displaying `audio` without controls.
 * Remove excess height in iOS 5 devices.
 */

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}


/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 7/8/9, Firefox 3, and Safari 4.
 * Known issue: no IE 6 support.
 */

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}


/**
 * 1. Correct text resizing oddly in IE 6/7 when body `font-size` is set using
 *    `em` units.
 * 2. Prevent iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling
 *    user zoom.
 */

html {
  font-size: 100%;
  /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
}


/**
 * Address `outline` inconsistency between Chrome and other browsers.
 */

a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
}


/**
 * Improve readability when focused and also mouse hovered in all browsers.
 */

a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0;
}


/**
 * 1. Remove border when inside `a` element in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 * 2. Improve image quality when scaled in IE 7.
 */

img {
  border: 0;
  /* 1 */
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  /* 2 */
}


/**
 * Address margin not present in IE 6/7/8/9, Safari 5, and Opera 11.
 */

figure {
  margin: 0;
}


/**
 * Correct margin displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */

form {
  margin: 0;
}


/**
 * Define consistent border, margin, and padding.
 */

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}


/**
 * 1. Correct color not being inherited in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Correct text not wrapping in Firefox 3.
 * 3. Correct alignment displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */

legend {
  border: 0;
  /* 1 */
  padding: 0;
  white-space: normal;
  /* 2 */
  *margin-left: -7px;
  /* 3 */
}


/**
 * 1. Correct font size not being inherited in all browsers.
 * 2. Address margins set differently in IE 6/7, Firefox 3+, Safari 5,
 *    and Chrome.
 * 3. Improve appearance and consistency in all browsers.
 */

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-size: 100%;
  /* 1 */
  margin: 0;
  /* 2 */
  vertical-align: baseline;
  /* 3 */
  *vertical-align: middle;
  /* 3 */
}


/**
 * Address Firefox 3+ setting `line-height` on `input` using `!important` in
 * the UA stylesheet.
 */

button,
input {
  line-height: normal;
}


/**
 * Address inconsistent `text-transform` inheritance for `button` and `select`.
 * All other form control elements do not inherit `text-transform` values.
 * Correct `button` style inheritance in Chrome, Safari 5+, and IE 6+.
 * Correct `select` style inheritance in Firefox 4+ and Opera.
 */

button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}


/**
 * 1. Avoid the WebKit bug in Android 4.0.* where (2) destroys native `audio`
 *    and `video` controls.
 * 2. Correct inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS.
 * 3. Improve usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type
 *    `input` and others.
 * 4. Remove inner spacing in IE 7 without affecting normal text inputs.
 *    Known issue: inner spacing remains in IE 6.
 */

button,
html input[type="button"],

/* 1 */

input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 2 */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* 3 */
  *overflow: visible;
  /* 4 */
}


/**
 * Re-set default cursor for disabled elements.
 */

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}


/**
 * 1. Address box sizing set to content-box in IE 8/9.
 * 2. Remove excess padding in IE 8/9.
 * 3. Remove excess padding in IE 7.
 *    Known issue: excess padding remains in IE 6.
 */

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* 1 */
  padding: 0;
  /* 2 */
  *height: 13px;
  /* 3 */
  *width: 13px;
  /* 3 */
}


/**
 * 1. Address `appearance` set to `searchfield` in Safari 5 and Chrome.
 * 2. Address `box-sizing` set to `border-box` in Safari 5 and Chrome
 *    (include `-moz` to future-proof).
 */

input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  /* 1 */
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  /* 2 */
  box-sizing: content-box;
}


/**
 * Remove inner padding and search cancel button in Safari 5 and Chrome
 * on OS X.
 */

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}


/**
 * Remove inner padding and border in Firefox 3+.
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/**
 * 1. Remove default vertical scrollbar in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Improve readability and alignment in all browsers.
 */

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  /* 1 */
  vertical-align: top;
  /* 2 */
}


/**
 * Remove most spacing between table cells.
 */

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  color: rgb(59, 173, 227);
}

::-moz-selection {
  background: #b3d4fc;
  text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
  background: #b3d4fc;
  text-shadow: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.chromeframe {
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0.2em 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Ultimate Shop</title>
  <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/adaptive.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/tooltip.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/range.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- <link href="css/slider.css"   rel="stylesheet"> -->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="product-info">
      <div class="product-image-box">
        <div class="product-image" style="background-image: url('.$row['image'].');">
          <div class="product-title-box">
            <p class="product-title unselectable">Ultimate Arena</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="product-navigation-buttons unselectable">
        <li class="product-description-button" id="product-navigation-button-active">Описание</li>
        <li class="product-setting-button">Настройки</li>
        <li class="product-install-button">Установка</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="product-info-content">
        <table class="product-info-short unselectable">
          <tr>
            <td>Версия:</td>
            <td>1.0.0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Автор:</td>
            <td>Nunf</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Файлы входящие в плагин:</td>
            <td>
              <a class="badge">ultimate_arena.cfg</a>
              <a class="badge">ultimate_arena.cfg</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Стоимость:</td>
            <td>999<i class="fas fa-ruble-sign" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <p style="background-color: red;">В процессе изучения материалов форума всё-таки решил написать краткую компиляцию литературы по обсуждаемому вопросу (в частности, диетам и "здоровому питанию"). Если кому-то интересно откуда я взял всё изложенное ниже - я приведу список литературы
          для подробного изучения. Ещё извиняюсь, если при упрощении материала где-то допустил неточность или искажение - прошу указать и поправить. Только, чур, аргументированно а не вот так: "я слышала, так не бывает" или "а я - не такая". Так же для
          чтения всего этого хорошо бы знать что такое обмен веществ (метаболизм), основной обмен веществ, белки, жиры, "быстрые" и "медленные" углеводы, калории, низкий и высокий гликемический индекс. В организме человека есть два источника энергии -
          гликоген (полисахарид), запасается в печени и мышечной ткани. Человек весом 75 кг может запасти 400 грамм гликогена ы мышцах (это 1600 ккал) и 80 грамм - в печени (320 ккал). Итого - 1920 ккал. Гликоген мышц используы мышцах (это 1600 ккал)
          и 80 грамм - в печени (320 ккал). Итого - 1920 ккал. Гликоген мышц используется непосредственно мышцой для покрытия собственных энергетических затрат, гликоген печени позволяет поддержать на определённом уровне уровень сахара в крови в целом,
          что бы "в случае чего" восполнить нехватку там где он (гликоген) нужен. А вот в жировой ткани можно спрятать намного больше энергии. 1 кг жира - это почти 8750 ккал. Но и нужны они не в повседневной жизни, по крайней мере человеку, который нормально
          питается и не голодает. Жир спасает животных (и человека) в экстремальных условиях - когда запасы гликогена почти исчерпаны. Ещё спасает от холода - но я видел мало людей которые пользуются своим жиром в этом направлении. То есть, если человек
          решил поголодать, например, "по Малахову", то организм будет действовать в такой последовательности: 1) поживёт недельку на остатках гликогена, ожидая нормального питания, попутно замедлянедельку на остатках гликогена, ожидая нормального питания,
          попутно замедляя обмен веществ что бы адаптироваться к новой схеме энергоснабжения. К концу 2-3 дня начнёт пережигать мышечную ткань (процесс катаболизма), так как этим убъёт сразу двух зайцев - килограмм мышц "съедает" 50 ккал в день, и в то
          же время они являются более легкоусвояемым топливом по сравнению с жиром. 2) Когда организм через неделю-две понимает, что здравый смысл в хозяине всё ещё не победил (у всех этот процесс "размышлений" занимает разное время, я имею в виду "размышления"
          организма, а не хозяина - там всё сложнее :-) ) - переходит на использование жировых запасов, но обмен веществ тормозить не перестаёт. Вспомните медведей, как они впадают в спячку - у них жира полно, они 3-4 месяца им могут питаться не напрягаясь.
          Правда, в спячке у них в разы замедляется дыхание, пульс, мозговая активность и падает давление и температура тела. Но если вам в реальных условиях это не помешат, например, ходить на работу (да ещё и работать) - остаётся только позавидовать
          вашей работе, если там ещё и платят нормально. Вам тогда можно голодать. Итак, для того что бы эффективно бороться с жиром для начала следует узнать а откуда он берётся в таких количествах, что приводит к росту жировой ткани, а что - к её исчезновению.
          Жировая ткань - это, как известно, совокупность жировых клеток (адипоцитов). Жировая ткань бывает двух видов - белая и бурая, но, поскольку в организме взрослого человека бурой жировой ткани мало, мы её рассматривать не будем. Жировая клетка
          (белой ткани) представляет собой шарик, внутри которого находится жировой пузырёк. О ней важно знать два факта: 1) По мере накопления внутри клетки жира (триглицеридов), клетка "раздувается", но раздуваться до бесконечности она не может, у неё
          есть предел. 2) В организме человека есть уже сформировавшиеся жировые клетки и запас (2-3 раза больший по числу) так называемых "вспомогательных" жировых клеток, которые не могут накапливать жир, но легко (и необратимо!) эволюционируют в жировую
          клетку если соседние с ней клетки забиты запасами жира "до упора". Вывод №1: количество жировой ткани за счёт количества клеток может только расти. А наша задача - не доводить имеющуюся ткань до такого состояния. Вывод №2: Ещё одно следствие
          - жировые клетки не могут "сгореть", а только уменьшиться в размерах за счёт опорожнения и переработки их внутренних запасов. Теперь стоит сказать по поводу распределения запасов жира в организме. Жировая клетка содержит 2 типа рецепторов, позволяющих
          ей понять что же от неё требуется - запасти жир или отдать его на "переработку". Это так называемые альфа-2- и бета-рецепторы. Рецепторы "вылавливают" из крови гормоны (в нашем случае важны: адреналин и норадреналин, инсулин и глюкогон) и либо
          запускают процесс синтеза в клетке жира (вылавливая так же из крови жирные кислоты и глюкозу), это называется липогенезом, либо опорожняют клетку, насыщая кровь запасёнными жирными кислотами (это липолиз - самый полезный для наших целей процесс)
          . Альфа рецепторы отвечают за липогенез, бета-рецепторы - за липолиз. Самый примечательный для нас факт: жировая ткань на бёдрах, ягодицах, внутренней поверхности бедра, вообщем весь низ тела - более насыщены альфа-рецепторами, в то время как
          верх тела - бета-рецепторами. Поэтому "низ" отдаёт жиры очень неохотно, зато грудь худеет "на ура". В западных источниках есть публикации по поводу возможности вырождения жировой клетки до её первоначального состояния, но вырождения жировой
          клетки до её первоначального состояния, но ещё нет доказательств, что такой процесс вообще возможен в организме. Когда будет - проблема лишнего веса будет решена раз и навсегда Вывод №1: количество жировой ткани за счёт количества клеток может
          только расти. А наша задача - не доводить имеющуюся ткань до такого состояния. Вывод №2: Ещё одно следствие - жировые клетки не могут "сгореть", а только уменьшиться в размерах за счёт опорожнения и переработки их внутренних запасов. -----------
          Продолжение, часть 2-ая и не последняя ---------------- Снова подведу некоторые итоги предыдущей части что бы облегчить понимание следующей (если что-то не понятно - срочно читать начало): - Стимулирующее воздействие на липолиз оказывают глюкагон
          (ещё соматотропин - гормон роста, но механизмы их действия различны и находятся за рамками нашей темы). - Тормозящее липолиз (и стимулирующее липогенез) действие оказывает инсулин. - Адреналин и норадреналин так же активизируют ферменты, необходимые
          для липолиза. При сильном стрессе интенсивное расщепление липидов является одной из причин потери веса. Итого: хотим худеть - держим уровень сахара на постоянном уровне, не допускаем его скачков (в рационе преобладают медленные углеводы), не
          даём жировой клетке материа(в рационе преобладают медленные углеводы), не даём жировой клетке материалов для строительства нового запаса жиров (триглициридов) (не допускаем значительного потребления жирного вместе со сладким за один приём пищи).
          Этого достаточно что бы не толстеть. Но..... чаще-то хочется убрать всё что уже нажито непосильным трудом. Да и, в конце концов, привлекательная, подтянутая фигура - это хорошо, но для многих не может быть целью жизни, и в этой самой жизни есть
          ещё куча других радостей, если не торты, то, по крайней мере, посиделки с подругами в суши-баре. То есть наша цель - балансировать около уровня вашего выбранного "идеального" веса. Поэтому, теперь когда нам известно какие процессы идут в ораганизме
          и что их регулирует рассмотрим два пути расходы лишнего жира: Голодание. Ничего нового сказать не могу, про медведя я уже писал. Важно знать, что если кто-то говорит что "я голодал три недели, потерял 30 кг, со 150 до 120" - это не значит что
          вы можете за неделю скинуть десятку. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, этот вариант мне подходит, но у моей таблицы есть отступы с лева и права(margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px;) на что я могу заменить margin что бы <p style="background: #color;"></p> не игнорировал их?

Comment: @Nunf, например на `border` прозрачного цвета rgba(0,0,0,0).

Comment: border прозрачного цвета создается с цветом таким же как и у таблицы, а не как у заднего фона, если сделать цвет такой же как у заднего фона, то на соеденении цвета border'a и заднего фона видно какую-то белую линию и самое главное почему border не подходит, так это то, что тень от box-shadow будет идти уже не от таблицы, а от border'a

Comment: @Nunf почитайте про border-clip

Comment: Нашел background-clip, менял его значения в table и в p, но мне так и не удалось сделать тень над border'om

Comment: @Nunf, обновил код в ответе. Если это не то что вам нужно, я не понимаю в чем ваша проблема. Объясните толком. И к слову, в исходном вопросе ничего про тень не было.

Comment: Сейчас отвечу Вам, после этого ответа Вы должны понять что я хочу сделать. Извените если не понятно изьясняюсь. Тень вокруг таблицы была, просто я натупил когда прикреплял код

Comment: Уже давно box-shadow вокруг таблицы есть в моем посте, когда Вы впервые дали ответ я его еще не добавил

Comment: @Nunf, так не нужно делать. Один вопрос - одна проблема.

Comment: Он и был изначально, просто я когда верстал эту страницу, делал все в devtools chrome. Потом меня попросили добавить код в пост и добавлял код из файлов, добавил и понял что я еще не добавил код который я не перенес из devtools в файлы

Comment: В посте добавил скрин как я хочу сделать

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {
 overflow: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #181f4b;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: #969dcd;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 0px;
 background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 background: #FF0000;
}

.unselectable {
 user-select: none;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
}

.main-container {
 height: 100%;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

.fas.fa-ruble-sign {
 font-size: 21px;
 background-color: #ffb400;
 padding: 2px;
 margin-left: 5px;
}

.product-info {
 margin: 0 20%;
 background: #252f67;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.product-image-box {
 width: 100%;
}

.product-image {
 padding: 30% 0 0 0;
 position: relative;
 background: no-repeat center center;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #0a55f7;
}

.product-title-box {
 width: auto;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 padding: 11%;
 text-align: center;
}

.product-title-box > .product-title {
 overflow: hidden;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 50px;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.product-navigation-buttons {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 13px;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: 600;
 background: #3b498b;
 display: block;
}

.product-navigation-buttons > li {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 33.3333333333%;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.product-navigation-buttons > li:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background: #495aa9;
}

#product-navigation-button-active {
 background: #495aa9;
}

.product-info-content {
 padding: 15px;
 color: #fff;
 font: 14px / 1.4 sans-serif;
 font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.product-info-content a {
 display: block;
}

.product-info-short {
 border-collapse: separate;
 border-spacing: 10px;
 background: #3b498b;
 float: right;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.product-info-short td:last-child {
 text-align: center;
}

.product-info-short a {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.product-info-short a:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: 0.4s;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ffb400;
 transform: translateX(-2px) translateY(-2px);
}

.product-info-content .fas.fa-ruble-sign {
 font-size: 15px;
 margin-left: 3px;
}

.badge {
 background: #495aa9;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: .25em .3em;
 font-size: 80%;
 font-weight: 600;
 line-height: 1;
 text-align: center;
 white-space: nowrap;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 border-radius: .25rem;
 transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out,background-color 0.15s ease-in-out,border-color 0.15s ease-in-out,box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

/*reset css*/
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
   v2.0-modified | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* make sure to set some focus styles for accessibility */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}

body {
 line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

input[type=search] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

textarea {
    overflow: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
    resize: vertical;
}

/**
 * Correct `inline-block` display not defined in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 */

audio,
canvas,
video {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}

/**
 * Prevent modern browsers from displaying `audio` without controls.
 * Remove excess height in iOS 5 devices.
 */

audio:not([controls]) {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 7/8/9, Firefox 3, and Safari 4.
 * Known issue: no IE 6 support.
 */

[hidden] {
    display: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct text resizing oddly in IE 6/7 when body `font-size` is set using
 *    `em` units.
 * 2. Prevent iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling
 *    user zoom.
 */

html {
    font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Address `outline` inconsistency between Chrome and other browsers.
 */

a:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
}

/**
 * Improve readability when focused and also mouse hovered in all browsers.
 */

a:active,
a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}

/**
 * 1. Remove border when inside `a` element in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 * 2. Improve image quality when scaled in IE 7.
 */

img {
    border: 0; /* 1 */
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Address margin not present in IE 6/7/8/9, Safari 5, and Opera 11.
 */

figure {
    margin: 0;
}

/**
 * Correct margin displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */

form {
    margin: 0;
}

/**
 * Define consistent border, margin, and padding.
 */

fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct color not being inherited in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Correct text not wrapping in Firefox 3.
 * 3. Correct alignment displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */

legend {
    border: 0; /* 1 */
    padding: 0;
    white-space: normal; /* 2 */
    *margin-left: -7px; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * 1. Correct font size not being inherited in all browsers.
 * 2. Address margins set differently in IE 6/7, Firefox 3+, Safari 5,
 *    and Chrome.
 * 3. Improve appearance and consistency in all browsers.
 */

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
    margin: 0; /* 2 */
    vertical-align: baseline; /* 3 */
    *vertical-align: middle; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * Address Firefox 3+ setting `line-height` on `input` using `!important` in
 * the UA stylesheet.
 */

button,
input {
    line-height: normal;
}

/**
 * Address inconsistent `text-transform` inheritance for `button` and `select`.
 * All other form control elements do not inherit `text-transform` values.
 * Correct `button` style inheritance in Chrome, Safari 5+, and IE 6+.
 * Correct `select` style inheritance in Firefox 4+ and Opera.
 */

button,
select {
    text-transform: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Avoid the WebKit bug in Android 4.0.* where (2) destroys native `audio`
 *    and `video` controls.
 * 2. Correct inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS.
 * 3. Improve usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type
 *    `input` and others.
 * 4. Remove inner spacing in IE 7 without affecting normal text inputs.
 *    Known issue: inner spacing remains in IE 6.
 */

button,
html input[type="button"], /* 1 */
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button; /* 2 */
    cursor: pointer; /* 3 */
    *overflow: visible;  /* 4 */
}

/**
 * Re-set default cursor for disabled elements.
 */

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
}

/**
 * 1. Address box sizing set to content-box in IE 8/9.
 * 2. Remove excess padding in IE 8/9.
 * 3. Remove excess padding in IE 7.
 *    Known issue: excess padding remains in IE 6.
 */

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
    padding: 0; /* 2 */
    *height: 13px; /* 3 */
    *width: 13px; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * 1. Address `appearance` set to `searchfield` in Safari 5 and Chrome.
 * 2. Address `box-sizing` set to `border-box` in Safari 5 and Chrome
 *    (include `-moz` to future-proof).
 */

input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /* 2 */
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and search cancel button in Safari 5 and Chrome
 * on OS X.
 */

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and border in Firefox 3+.
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/**
 * 1. Remove default vertical scrollbar in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Improve readability and alignment in all browsers.
 */

textarea {
    overflow: auto; /* 1 */
    vertical-align: top; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove most spacing between table cells.
 */

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: rgb(59,173,227);
}


::-moz-selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

fieldset {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

textarea {
    resize: vertical;
}

.chromeframe {
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.2em 0;
}

/* Modified */
.product-info-content span {
 display: block;
 background-color: #3b498b;
}
.product-info-content .product-info-short {
 background-color: #252f67;
 box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>Ultimate Shop</title>
 <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/adaptive.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/tooltip.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/range.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- <link href="css/slider.css"   rel="stylesheet"> -->
</head>
<body>
 <div class="content">
  <div class="product-info">
   <div class="product-image-box">
    <div class="product-image" style="background-image: url('.$row['image'].');">
     <div class="product-title-box">
      <p class="product-title unselectable">Ultimate Arena</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <ul class="product-navigation-buttons unselectable">
    <li class="product-description-button" id="product-navigation-button-active">Описание</li>
    <li class="product-setting-button">Настройки</li>
    <li class="product-install-button">Установка</li>
   </ul>
   <div class="product-info-content">
    <table class="product-info-short unselectable">
     <tr>
      <td>Версия:</td>
      <td>1.0.0</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Автор:</td>
      <td>Nunf</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Файлы входящие в плагин:</td>
      <td>
       <a class="badge">ultimate_arena.cfg</a>
       <a class="badge">ultimate_arena.cfg</a>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Стоимость:</td>
      <td>999<i class="fas fa-ruble-sign" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <span style="background: #3b498b;">В процессе изучения материалов форума всё-таки решил написать краткую компиляцию литературы по обсуждаемому вопросу (в частности, диетам и "здоровому питанию"). Если кому-то интересно откуда я взял всё изложенное ниже - я приведу список литературы для подробного изучения. Ещё извиняюсь, если при упрощении материала где-то допустил неточность или искажение - прошу указать и поправить. Только, чур, аргументированно а не вот так: "я слышала, так не бывает" или "а я - не такая". Так же для чтения всего этого хорошо бы знать что такое обмен веществ (метаболизм), основной обмен веществ, белки, жиры, "быстрые" и "медленные" углеводы, калории, низкий и высокий гликемический индекс. В организме человека есть два источника энергии - гликоген (полисахарид), запасается в печени и мышечной ткани. Человек весом 75 кг может запасти 400 грамм гликогена ы мышцах (это 1600 ккал) и 80 грамм - в печени (320 ккал). Итого - 1920 ккал. Гликоген мышц используы мышцах (это 1600 ккал) и 80 грамм - в печени (320 ккал). Итого - 1920 ккал. Гликоген мышц используется непосредственно мышцой для покрытия собственных энергетических затрат, гликоген печени позволяет поддержать на определённом уровне уровень сахара в крови в целом, что бы "в случае чего" восполнить нехватку там где он (гликоген) нужен. А вот в жировой ткани можно спрятать намного больше энергии. 1 кг жира - это почти 8750 ккал. Но и нужны они не в повседневной жизни, по крайней мере человеку, который нормально питается и не голодает. Жир спасает животных (и человека) в экстремальных условиях - когда запасы гликогена почти исчерпаны. Ещё спасает от холода - но я видел мало людей которые пользуются своим жиром в этом направлении. То есть, если человек решил поголодать, например, "по Малахову", то организм будет действовать в такой последовательности: 1) поживёт недельку на остатках гликогена, ожидая нормального питания, попутно замедлянедельку на остатках гликогена, ожидая нормального питания, попутно замедляя обмен веществ что бы адаптироваться к новой схеме энергоснабжения. К концу 2-3 дня начнёт пережигать мышечную ткань (процесс катаболизма), так как этим убъёт сразу двух зайцев - килограмм мышц "съедает" 50 ккал в день, и в то же время они являются более легкоусвояемым топливом по сравнению с жиром. 2) Когда организм через неделю-две понимает, что здравый смысл в хозяине всё ещё не победил (у всех этот процесс "размышлений" занимает разное время, я имею в виду "размышления" организма, а не хозяина - там всё сложнее :-) ) - переходит на использование жировых запасов, но обмен веществ тормозить не перестаёт. Вспомните медведей, как они впадают в спячку - у них жира полно, они 3-4 месяца им могут питаться не напрягаясь. Правда, в спячке у них в разы замедляется дыхание, пульс, мозговая активность и падает давление и температура тела. Но если вам в реальных условиях это не помешат, например, ходить на работу (да ещё и работать) - остаётся только позавидовать вашей работе, если там ещё и платят нормально. Вам тогда можно голодать. Итак, для того что бы эффективно бороться с жиром для начала следует узнать а откуда он берётся в таких количествах, что приводит к росту жировой ткани, а что - к её исчезновению. Жировая ткань - это, как известно, совокупность жировых клеток (адипоцитов). Жировая ткань бывает двух видов - белая и бурая, но, поскольку в организме взрослого человека бурой жировой ткани мало, мы её рассматривать не будем. Жировая клетка (белой ткани) представляет собой шарик, внутри которого находится жировой пузырёк. О ней важно знать два факта: 1) По мере накопления внутри клетки жира (триглицеридов), клетка "раздувается", но раздуваться до бесконечности она не может, у неё есть предел. 2) В организме человека есть уже сформировавшиеся жировые клетки и запас (2-3 раза больший по числу) так называемых "вспомогательных" жировых клеток, которые не могут накапливать жир, но легко (и необратимо!) эволюционируют в жировую клетку если соседние с ней клетки забиты запасами жира "до упора". Вывод №1: количество жировой ткани за счёт количества клеток может только расти. А наша задача - не доводить имеющуюся ткань до такого состояния. Вывод №2: Ещё одно следствие - жировые клетки не могут "сгореть", а только уменьшиться в размерах за счёт опорожнения и переработки их внутренних запасов. Теперь стоит сказать по поводу распределения запасов жира в организме. Жировая клетка содержит 2 типа рецепторов, позволяющих ей понять что же от неё требуется - запасти жир или отдать его на "переработку". Это так называемые альфа-2- и бета-рецепторы. Рецепторы "вылавливают" из крови гормоны (в нашем случае важны: адреналин и норадреналин, инсулин и глюкогон) и либо запускают процесс синтеза в клетке жира (вылавливая так же из крови жирные кислоты и глюкозу), это называется липогенезом, либо опорожняют клетку, насыщая кровь запасёнными жирными кислотами (это липолиз - самый полезный для наших целей процесс) . Альфа рецепторы отвечают за липогенез, бета-рецепторы - за липолиз. Самый примечательный для нас факт: жировая ткань на бёдрах, ягодицах, внутренней поверхности бедра, вообщем весь низ тела - более насыщены альфа-рецепторами, в то время как верх тела - бета-рецепторами. Поэтому "низ" отдаёт жиры очень неохотно, зато грудь худеет "на ура". В западных источниках есть публикации по поводу возможности вырождения жировой клетки до её первоначального состояния, но вырождения жировой клетки до её первоначального состояния, но ещё нет доказательств, что такой процесс вообще возможен в организме. Когда будет - проблема лишнего веса будет решена раз и навсегда Вывод №1: количество жировой ткани за счёт количества клеток может только расти. А наша задача - не доводить имеющуюся ткань до такого состояния. Вывод №2: Ещё одно следствие - жировые клетки не могут "сгореть", а только уменьшиться в размерах за счёт опорожнения и переработки их внутренних запасов. ----------- Продолжение, часть 2-ая и не последняя ---------------- Снова подведу некоторые итоги предыдущей части что бы облегчить понимание следующей (если что-то не понятно - срочно читать начало): - Стимулирующее воздействие на липолиз оказывают глюкагон (ещё соматотропин - гормон роста, но механизмы их действия различны и находятся за рамками нашей темы). - Тормозящее липолиз (и стимулирующее липогенез) действие оказывает инсулин. - Адреналин и норадреналин так же активизируют ферменты, необходимые для липолиза. При сильном стрессе интенсивное расщепление липидов является одной из причин потери веса. Итого: хотим худеть - держим уровень сахара на постоянном уровне, не допускаем его скачков (в рационе преобладают медленные углеводы), не даём жировой клетке материа(в рационе преобладают медленные углеводы), не даём жировой клетке материалов для строительства нового запаса жиров (триглициридов) (не допускаем значительного потребления жирного вместе со сладким за один приём пищи). Этого достаточно что бы не толстеть. Но..... чаще-то хочется убрать всё что уже нажито непосильным трудом. Да и, в конце концов, привлекательная, подтянутая фигура - это хорошо, но для многих не может быть целью жизни, и в этой самой жизни есть ещё куча других радостей, если не торты, то, по крайней мере, посиделки с подругами в суши-баре. То есть наша цель - балансировать около уровня вашего выбранного "идеального" веса. Поэтому, теперь когда нам известно какие процессы идут в ораганизме и что их регулирует рассмотрим два пути расходы лишнего жира: Голодание. Ничего нового сказать не могу, про медведя я уже писал. Важно знать, что если кто-то говорит что "я голодал три недели, потерял 30 кг, со 150 до 120" - это не значит что вы можете за неделю скинуть десятку.
    </span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Поправил лишь два стиля: **.product-info-content span** и **.product-info-content .product-info-short** .

```
.product-info-content span {
    display: block;
    background-color: #3b498b;
}
```

Либо заменить с **span** на **p**.

```
.product-info-content .product-info-short {
    background-color: #252f67;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Убрал тень и заменил цвет чтобы он выглядел монолитно.

Comment: Спасибо, но это не то